# Not able to see disassembled code of if-else statements

Tags: c, gdb, disassembly

I wanted to see how the disassembly of an if-else program written in C looks like inside GDB. To keep things simple, I created the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if(5==6)
        printf("They are equal");
    else
        printf("Not equal");

    return 0;
}
```

I knew some basics of disassembly so I was expecting the presence of "test" or "je" instruction but it showed the following disassembled code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001139 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000113a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+4>:     lea    rdi,[rip+0xec0]        # 0x2004
   0x0000000000001144 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001149 <+16>:    call   0x1030 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000000114e <+21>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001153 <+26>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001154 <+27>:    ret
```

Now I think that the absence of those "comparison" instructions is due to compiler optimizations. So I used the **-O0** flag with gcc to compile the C program with optimizations disabled. After compiling, I checked the disassembly and got the following result:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001139 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000113a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+4>:     lea    rdi,[rip+0xec0]        # 0x2004
   0x0000000000001144 <+11>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001149 <+16>:    call   0x1030 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000000114e <+21>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001153 <+26>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001154 <+27>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Again, there were no instructions like "test" or "je" even after disabling the compiler optimization.

Now my question is:

- Why can't I see the comparison instructions even after disabling compiler optimization?
- How can I see the raw disassembly of the written code?

Comment: Apparently your compiler has a built-in lie-detector ;)

Comment: change to `if (argc == 1)` and add argc to main.

Comment: You aren't going to see a `test` instruction because the compiler can evaluate `5 == 6` at compile time. So the `if` statement is essentially `if (0)`. And you aren't going to see a branch instruction because of the following warning: *"code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]"* So the only thing to learn here is that you should enable compiler warnings, read the compiler warnings, and fix the code. Otherwise, you're just wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5==6` is a constant expression, so perhaps even with optimizations off, its still evaluated to `false` at compile time. Try making them volatile:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    volatile int x = 5, y = 6;
    if(x==y)
        printf("They are equal");
    else
        printf("Not equal");

    return 0;
}
```